# setTimeout causing memory leak

Tags: javascript

```
var SetInactivityTimeOut = function () {
    try {
        var TimeoutInterval = parseInt(10, 10);

        var PreviousTimeStamp = Math.round(new Date().getHours() * 60 + new Date().getMinutes());

        if (TimeoutInterval === 0) return;

        TimeoutInterval = TimeoutInterval * 60 * 1000; //Converting to milisecond
        var TimeOutObj;
        if (TimeOutObj != null && TimeOutObj != undefined) {
            clearTimeout(TimeOutObj);
        }
        //Ti.API.info('TimeOutObj---'+TimeOutObj);
        TimeOutObj = setTimeout(function () {
            open the main page
        },TimeoutInterval);

    } catch (e) {
        error(e);
    }
}
```

This is the function i am using on every button click, once 10 minutes idle time has been finished, it opens back the index page. But when i try to login the application from there, its very slow and application gets hanged.

I am using this code in Mobile. I just wanted to know is there any memory leak in the way the function is written.

Comment: @H2CO3 Deleting a bad answer does not make you right. You have a ton of reputation, please don't spread false information. SO is used by quite a lot of people and it has become analogous to wikipedia in many ways. Keep the standards high. Please.

Answer (score 3):

As you have your function at the moment, `TimeOutObj` is being declared in the same function that you check to see if it exists, it will always exist but will always be `undefined` at the point where you are checking to see if it is a timeout id, so you will never actually clear the timeout.

By wrapping the majority of your `SetInteractivityTimeout` function in a closure, you can declare the `TimeOutObj` outside of the scope of the actual handling function, so it will maintain its value each time you call the `SetInactivityTimeout` function.

```
var SetInactivityTimeOut = (function () {
   var TimeOutObj;
   var TimeoutInterval = 10 * 60 * 1000; //Converting to milisecond

   return function() {
     if (TimeOutObj) {
       clearTimeout(TimeOutObj);
     }

     TimeOutObj = setTimeout(function () {
       // open the main page
     }, TimeoutInterval);
   }
 }());
```